# How do I remove all occurrences of certain latex commands from a tex file

Tags: macros

In my tex file I have a bunch of commands of the form `\bla{ ... }`, where the `...` may span several lines. These commands `\bla{ ... }` contain some notes for myself, and should be removed from the tex file before sending it to my publisher. Note that I am supposed to send the tex file, not the pdf, so I cannot simply redefine the `\bla` macro to an empty macro. Any thoughts on how to do this as quickly as possible with a linux terminal command? (Or any other trick)

Comment: So, what you want is to delete everything from `\bla{` to `}`? The problem is that you have to take care of nested braces, for example, `\bla{foo \textit{faa}}`. You can not delete until first `}`.

Comment: yes, even if there are new lines, and yes the nested braces are the one of the issues (also new lines).

Comment: So, maybe it is better to ask on another SE site, maybe StackOverflow, and ask how to manipulate text files and strings.

Comment: Half joke, half serious: Does it take more time trying to find out a way to do this automatically or just doing it by hand? `;-)`

Comment: I made a simple program in C that did it in about 30 min, doing it by hand would have taken me longer I think,  and this is not the first time I run into this. So it seemed to be worth the efford

Comment: @mnr can you post your code? I'd love to be able to do this automatically